# Level Translation Clarification (LVPECL and LVDS)

Tags: differential, conversion, lvds, level-translation

I am trying to understand something about level translation. I am sure I am probably misunderstanding something basic, so I'm hoping you can help me understand.

I am trying to convert a LVPECL signal to LVDS (from the search I have seen a lot of the opposites). I understand that for LVPECL high is from 3.3 to 2.4 and low is 1.6 to 0/GND while in LVDS, high is ~1.4 to ~2.5-3.3 and low is 1 to 0/GND.
I am looking at this https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Differential%20Clock.pdf (mainly page 6).

My confusion arises from the figure. I am assuming the LVPECL driver/triangle is just my device outputting the LVPECL signal and the LVDS receiver is my device that takes in a LVDS signal/where I want to input it. I assume Zo=50 is just the cable and the intrinsic impedance that connects the output to input. So my question is, if I want to convert LVPECL to LCDS, do I just need to add the other resisters and capacitors to ground and power supply? I don't think I've ever seen this and it sounds pretty jank/sketchy in my head which is probably where my confusion arises from.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: TI's [application report](https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/scaa059) says pretty much the same.

Comment: @CL. , so are my assumptions correct then (just for the future)? If I just solder resisters to the appropriate passive device (Ground, Power, short), then it should convert it? 
Also, is there any way to know the delay/skew prior to building it?